# Is supervision tree available in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the [OTP Design Principles User's Guide](https://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html):

> A basic concept in Erlang/OTP is the supervision tree. This is a process structuring model based on the idea of workers and supervisors. Workers are processes that perform computations, that is, they do the actual work.
> Supervisors are processes that monitor the behaviour of workers. A supervisor can restart a worker if something goes wrong.

My question is that if supervision tree is available in Python?

Comment: Please read the [help/on-topic] before posting here; library recommendations are specifically not allowed on this site: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you. I didn't know that. The reason I mentioned the library names was to ensure the readers that I didn’t only post the question here without initial search. I modified the question.